# Given $9$ numbered red marbles and $7$ numbered blue marbles, find the probability that a marble drawn at random is blue or even-numbered

Tags: probability

A jar contains $9$ red marbles numbered $1$ to $9$ and $7$ blue marbles numbered $1$ to $7$. A marble is drawn at random from the jar. Find the probability that the marble is blue or even-numbered.

Answer (score 2):

How many marbles fit the criterion? Now divide by the number of possibilities.

Comment: What? I'm confused and sleepy

Comment: @MeganCiao Try reading it again later.